# Export data from Google Analytics with R library RGA

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

If I have google analytics link like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%5A6389839&start-date=yesterday&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath%2Cga%3Adimension4%2Cga%3Adimension
```

What are the credentials to input in code below (ga$getData, ids, metrics and dimension are troubles) :

```
ga$getData(ids, batch = TRUE, start.date, end.date, 
           metrics = "ga:visits", dimensions = "ga:date,ga:medium,ga:source", 
           sort = "", filters = "", segment = "")
```

I have tried with so many inputs, but every one of them have some error. 
Thanks.